# How to ingest data from multiple resources with different schema

Tags: azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

I need to centralize the logs from multiples resource with different schema

For example

Schema in source1: Timestamp, errorcode, errordescription

Schema in source2: Timestamp, eventId, event description

Table is created as

`.create table TraceLog (Timestamp:datetime, errorcode:string, errordescription:string, eventId:string, eventdescription:string)`

For ingest data from source1, I cam simple use

`.ingest inline into Table TraceLog <| 2020-05-01, "error code", "test error description"`

For data from soruce2, except

`.ingest inline into Table TraceLog <| 2020-05-01, "", "", "test event ID", "test event description"`

any other way to ingest data without specify column in source1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be using ingestion mappings per different source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings

In case the data requires additional transformation (e.g. parsing): you can utilize Update Policy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried below command but failed 

.create table TraceLog ingestion csv mapping "testmapping" 
'[{"column":"TIMESTAMP","DataType":"datetime","Properties":{"Ordinal":"0"}},{ "column" : "EventID", "DataType":"string", "Properties":{"Ordinal":"1"}},{ "column" : "EventDescription", "DataType":"string", "Properties":{"Ordinal":"2"}}]'

.ingest into table TraceLog ("2020-05-17","183","restart service")  with (format='csv',ingestionMappingName="testmapping")

Comment: Thanks, I should upload csv file to azure blob instead using direct value